# Understanding exercise 2.29 SICP - Binary modules

Tags: scheme, sicp

Just one minor thing, I don´t understand why procedure `right-branch` is like this:

```
(define (right-branch mobile)
   (car (cdr mobile)))
```

instead of:

```
(define (right-branch mobile)
   (cdr mobile))
```

As far as I know, `car` procedure return the first item in a list and `cdr` returns the "rest" of the list. So, if we have a mobile like this:

```
((1 2) (3 4))
```

the left branch is `(1 2)` and the right branch is `(3 4)`. Is like this or am I missing something? Thanks.

And the same for procedure `branch-structure`.

Comment: If you were to evaluate `(cdr '((1 2) (3 4)))` you'd notice that it *isn't* `'(3 4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `(cdr '((1 2) (3 4)))` is *not* `'(3 4)`. Rather, it is `'((3 4))`.

This is because the list is a *list*, containing three elements: two lists and the empty list (`null`). That means the list, expressed as pairs, actually looks like this:

```
'((1 2) . ((3 4) . ()))
```

Since `cdr` gets the right side of a pair, it returns the *rest* of the list, so even if only one element is left, it is wrapped in a containing list.